Weak approximation in Krull domains
Suppose $R$ is a Krull domain with the field of fraction $K$. To every prime ideal $P$ of $R$ of height $1$, one can associate a $ \mathbb{Z}$-valued discrete valuation which we denote by $v_P$.
Suppose $P_1, \dots, P_k$ are pairwise distinct height one prime ideas of $R$. It is well-known that the following approximation theorem holds: for any $(n_1, \dots, n_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$, there exists $x \in K$ such that

$v_{P_i} (x)= n_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k$
$v_{P}(x) \ge 0$ for all prime ideals $P$ of $R$ of height one other than $P_1, \dots, P_k$.

I would like to know if one can replace (2) with $v_{P}(x) =  0$ for all all prime ideals $P$ of height one other than $P_1, \dots, P_k$, perhaps at the cost of extending the initial set to a larger set of prime ideals.
In case it helps, the case I am really interested in is when $R$ is an integral extension of $ \mathbb{Q}[X_1, \dots, X_n]$. Any reference would be highly appreciated.
Edit: To clarify the question, what I would like to know if the following refinement of the approximation lemma holds:
Given $P_1, \dots, P_k$ are above, there exists a finite set $\mathcal{P}$ of prime ideals of height $1$ only depending on $P_1, \dots, P_k$ so that for every vector $(n_i)_{1 \le i \le k} \in \mathbb{Z}^k$, there exists $x \in K$ such that in addition to satisfying (1) and (2) above, it also satisfies $v_{P}(x)=0$ for all height one prime ideals $P$ outside $\mathcal{P}$.
I interpret the comment below by @Laurent Moret-Bailly as a negative answer to this. If this is indeed the case, I would still like to see how this goes wrong.

I'm having a really hard time interpreting your  qualification "perhaps at the cost of..."  Can you give a  precise statement of what you mean?

@JesseElliott I added a paragraph clarifying the question.

Ah, thank you.  I think I've answered it in the positive, with my most recent edit.

Thanks a lot! Your solution is quite neat!

You're welcome!  I enjoyed working on it.

If you remove "perhaps at the cost of extending the initial [finite] set to a larger [finite] set of prime ideals" from your question, then the answer is yes for a fixed Krull domain $R$ if and only if $R$ is a UFD.  First, suppose that the answer is yes for $R$.  Then let $x$ be an element of $K$ such that $v_P(x) = 1$ for a fixed height one prime $P$ and $v_Q(x) = 0$ for all other height one primes $Q$.  It is clear, then, that $P$ is principal, generated by $x$.  (Check this.)  Since then all height one primes of $R$ are principal, $R$ is a UFD. Conversely, if $R$ is a UFD, then every height one prime  $P$ of $R$ is principal, say, generated by $x_P$, and then $x = x_{P_1}^{n_1} x_{P_2}^{n_2} \cdots x_{P_k}^{n_k}$ satisfies the required condition for $x$.
The OP's qualified statement is true for any Krull domain $R$.  Here is a proof.  For each $i $ from $1$ to $k$, there exist nonzero $x_i^+, x_i^- \in K$  such that $v_{P_i}(x_i^\pm) = \pm 1$,  $v_{P_j}(x_i^\pm) = 0$ for all $j \neq i$, and $v_{Q}(x_i^\pm) \geq 0$ for all $Q$ other than the $P_i$.  Since for any nonzero $y \in K$ one has $v_Q(y) = 0$ for all but finitely many height one primes $Q$, one has $v_Q(x_i^{\pm}) = 0$ for all $i $ for all but finitely many height one primes $Q$, so we may collect all $Q$ such that $v_Q(x_i^{\pm}) \neq 0$ for some $i$ into a finite set $\mathcal{P}$. Then, for any $(n_1,  n_2, \ldots, n_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$, the nonzero element $x= (x_1^\pm)^{|n_1|} (x_2^\pm)^{|n_2|} \cdots (x_k^\pm)^{|n_k|}$ of $K$, with the sign  of each $\pm$ in $x_i^{\pm}$  matching the sign of $n_i$,  satisfies the desired condition of the OP.

It should be observed that the primes added to the list depend on $x$. I think the question was not clear about this.

Thanks a lot for these answers. I would very much like to see in action how one if forced to accept these additional ideals. The situation I have to deal with involved integral extensions of $ \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Can one see in an example how this works?

@LaurentMoret-Bailly That's a good point!  I realize now that I don't know how to interpret the qualified statement and have asked Keivan Karai to make it precise.

I added a comment clarifying the question.

@KeivanKarai Thanks!  I had thought so but wanted to make sure.  I've edited my answer.  It's an interesting question, but I still I haven't made much progress. I've at least restated it in terms of the group of fractional ideals under divisorial multiplication, for what that's worth.

The software has told me this has been edited more than 20 times, and it's only 2 or so days old. If you find that you are starting to make lots of fixes, then please make a comment noting you are planning on fixing things, spend time off-site drafting and finishing edits, and then do one big edit.

@DavidRoberts I apologize.  I was having difficulty viewing what I was typing on my browser, because for some reason there was a large delay while I was typing.  Most of the edits were within several minutes of each other, because of typos.  But, point taken!

Thank you! This was a very neat solution!
